# Regarding CTS Error

Tags: android, cts, android-cts

How to kill a running CTS instance.Suppose one CTS instance is running 
on a terminal and if we abruptly close that terminal, that CTS 
instance will not be closed and when we try to start CTS again in a 
fresh terminal,we get this error[CTS_ERROR >>> Error: CTS is being 
used at the moment. No more than one CTS instance is allowed 
simultaneously] so how to go to CTS Host this time or kill this 
running instance.

Answer (score 2):

type command: ps -al -> it will show all running instances, and select appropriate running instance id (a integere value) like adb instance and kill that instance with following command: kill -9 id(integer value)